# Spark Dataframe Pivot without Overlapping in Pivoting Columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, pivot, collect

Say, I have a dataframe, df, such as:

```
Column_A    Columns_B    Column_C    Column_D    Priority

a_1         b_1          c_1         d_1         high
a_1         b_1          c_1         d_1         medium
a_1         b_1          c_1         d_1         low
a_1         b_1          c_1         d_2         high
a_1         b_1          c_1         d_3         medium
a_1         b_1          c_1         d_4         high
a_1         b_1          c_1         d_4         low
a_2         b_2          c_2         d_5         medium
a_2         b_2          c_2         d_5         low
a_2         b_2          c_2         d_6         high
a_2         b_2          c_2         d_7         low
```

Now if I collect values of Column D by applying groupBy on Columns A, B and C and then pivoting on Column Priority, the outcome will be:

```
scala> val outcome =  df.groupBy("Column_A", "Column_B", "Column_C")
                      .pivot("Priority", ("high", "medium", "low"))
                      .agg(collect_set("Column_D") as "Set_D")

scala> outcome.show

Column_A    Column_B    Column_C    High               Medium        Low

a_1         b_1         c_1         [d_1, d_2, d_4]    [d_1, d_3]    [d_1, d_4]
a_2         b_2         c_2         [d_6]              [d_5]         [d_5, d_7]
```

But I want the pivoting to be in an heirarchichal order, i.e., if, for a grouped columns (A, B, and C), the value of column D lies in **High** then it should not be in **Medium** nor in **Low**. Similarly, if the value lies in **Medium** then it should not be in **Low**. It's like exclusively collecting the values of Column D based on a heirarchy in pivoting columns.

The desired outcome:

```
scala> outcome.show

Column_A    Column_B    Column_C    High               Medium        Low

a_1         b_1         c_1         [d_1, d_2, d_4]    [d_3]         []
a_2         b_2         c_2         [d_6]              [d_5]         [d_7]
```

Suggestion to subtract column **High** from column **Medium** and similarly subtracting column **Medium** from column **Low** is not applicable because there could be any number of baskets in Column **Priority**, i.e, for example, Column **Priority** could have values like *("very high", "high", "medium", "low", "very low")*, etc.

**Edit:** The order of values of Priorities is determined by a score list. For example, [("high", 1), ("medium", 0.5), ("low", 0.25)] or [("very high", 1), ("high", 0.8), ("medium", 0.6), ("low", 0.4), ("very low", 0.2)]

Any lead would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: How can the order of the priorities be determined from the input data? Or is there always a fixed list available (like the second parameter of the `pivot` function)?

Comment: The order of values of Priorities is determined by a fixed score list. For example, [("high", 1), ("medium", 0.5), ("low", 0.25)] or [("very high", 1), ("high", 0.8), ("medium", 0.6), ("low", 0.4), ("very low", 0.2)]

Answer (score 0):

Substracting the arrays from each other could work if the list of scores is used to iterate over the columns in the correct order:

```scala
df = ...
outcome = ...

val scoreList: Seq[(String, Double)] = Seq(("very high", 1), ("high", 0.8), ("medium", 0.6), ("low", 0.4), ("very low", 0.2))

val actCols=scoreList.sortWith( _._2 > _._2)    //sort the list
  .filter( t => outcome.columns.contains(t._1)) //remove all columns that are not part of the actual dataset
  .map(_._1)                                    //only keep the column names

var cleanedUp=outcome

for( (col, i) <- actCols.tail.zipWithIndex) {   //iterate over all columns but the one with the highest prio
  val colsWithHigherPrio = actCols.take(i+1)    //consider all columns with higher prio than the current one
  for( c <- colsWithHigherPrio) {               //remove all values that are already present in columns with higher prio
    cleanedUp = cleanedUp.withColumn(col, functions.array_except(functions.col(col), functions.col(c)))
  }
}
cleanedUp.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------------+------+-----+
|Column_A|Column_B|Column_C|           high|medium|  low|
+--------+--------+--------+---------------+------+-----+
|     a_2|     b_2|     c_2|          [d_6]| [d_5]|[d_7]|
|     a_1|     b_1|     c_1|[d_1, d_2, d_4]| [d_3]|   []|
+--------+--------+--------+---------------+------+-----+
```

*Edit*: a very similar approach without using explict loops:

```scala
def cleanupSingleCol(df:DataFrame, cols:Seq[String]) = cols.tail.foldLeft(df)((d, c) =>
    d.withColumn(cols.head, functions.array_except(functions.col(cols.head), functions.col(c))))
val cleanedUp=actCols.inits.filter(_.size >= 2).foldLeft(outcome)((df, l) =>
    cleanupSingleCol(df, l.reverse))
```

Comment: This was my first thought too. But using loops in spark is kinda undermining its utility, let alone nested loops. I'm sure there must be a more efficient and concise way!! Maybe something along the tracks of using JOINS...thanks though for your kind suggestion :)

Comment: If you check the execution plan of `cleanedUp` you won't see any loops or shuffles. Any solution involving joins will be a lot slower at runtime as additionally Spark stages will be created